# How do you implement paging in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paging

Currently, I'm using a strategy found on many blog posts.  Basically, the URL contains the page number (e.g. /Users/List/5 will give you the users on page 5 of your paged list of users).  However, I'm not running into a situation where one page must list two separate paged lists.  How do I go about doing this using ASP.NET MVC?  Do I simply provide two url parameters (e.g. /Users/List?page1=1&page2=2)?  Is there a better way by using partial views?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ignoring routes for just a minute, you'll just keep the state of the 2 different pages in the URL as querystring parameters.

mysite.com/foo?list1page=2&list2page=8

Then you build the data/pagers accordingly.  The pager links will just update the url.

You can get creative with routes to create more friendly URLs, but I think querystring params are perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: What if you also have to keep up with multiple search parameters as well?

Comment: This becomes slightly more complex.  You'll probably want to have a helper take in some context and generate the appropriate URL.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [ASP.NET MvcPager](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=4224) on the official asp.net site.

Answer (score 2):

If you use query parameters then the page links in each list have to know about each other in-order to pass both parameters.

If the two lists are independent of each other then you can update them individually using jquery & ajax. Simply place each list in their own div as a partial view.

```
<div id="list1"><%= Html.RenderPartial ("ListA") %></div>
<div id="list2"><%= Html.RenderPartial ("ListB") %></div>
```

Lookup **ajaxSubmit** from the jQuery Form plugin for an easy way to update the lists.

Answer (score 1):

[PagedList.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc) is a really easy to use plugin, and is available via `Nuget` too.