# How Do I Create a Paging Feature like SOF with ListView?

Tags: asp.net, listview, paging

Every time you search for post on SOF, you can browse through the result with page-navigation feature. How do I create a Paging feature like SOF? I like that feature a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
    using MvcContrib.Pagination;
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
      var pageNo = page?? 1; // default to page 1
      var someEnumerable  = GetData(); // returns your collection
      var cutomPage = 
         PaginationHelper.AsPagination<SomeObject>(someEnumerable  , pageNo);
      return View(“Index”, CustomPage);
    }
```

Also have a look at this tutorial: [**NerdDinner Step 8: Paging Support**](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm)

> var paginatedDinners =
>   upcomingDinners.Skip(10).Take(20).ToList();

references:

- [**Powerful but easy paging with ASP.NET
  MVC**](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/johnk/2009/04/02/38871)
- [**How do you implement paging in
  ASP.NET MVC?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291893/how-do-you-implement-paging-in-asp-net-mvc)

---

**EDIT:** For Web-forms look at this Tutorial Series

- [**Paging and Sorting**](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/#pagingsorting)

Comment: Hey, How to do it with WebForm? Thanks.

Comment: have a look at EDIT, it is pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

Use the powerful DataPager control.

Here's a tutorial:

http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/127340.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RickStrahl+%28Rick+Strahl%27s+WebLog%29